# Is my PDO ECHO and RETURN statements correct?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, content-management-system

I was wondering why I am receiving syntax errors on lines 9 and 16 from my `PHP`/`PDO` coding.
My code is as follows:

```
<?php
// Sandbox Functions
// PDO example
function get_page($dbc, $pg) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch()
            echo '<h1>'.$page['title'].'</h1>';
        echo '<div class="content">'.$page['body'].'</div>';}
function get_title($dbc, $pg) {
    $sql = "SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch()
    return $page['title'];}
?>
```

Comment: as it returned error, you should know the answer already

Answer (score 0):

Put simicolon after that `$stmt->fetch()` like :  `$row = $stmt->fetch();`

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolons...

```
<?php
// Sandbox Functions
// PDO example
function get_page($dbc, $pg) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); //missing ;
            echo '<h1>'.$page['title'].'</h1>';
        echo '<div class="content">'.$page['body'].'</div>';}
function get_title($dbc, $pg) {
    $sql = "SELECT title FROM pages WHERE page = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); //missing ;
    return $page['title'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch()
```

Is not having a semicolon:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Same on the line 16:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch()
```

To

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```